# action doeesn't triggered in a4j:commandlink

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, richfaces

I am new at this but my action is not triggered.
In a4j:commandLink id="linklogout" I added a new action menubean.resetMenuActionVariables that does not work. I can use in the same file menubean and it works. But this action is not triggered.
I search on forums and I try to add a a4j:region or a4j:form around the commandlink but still does not work. Any ideas?
The code is below:

```
<div id="adminView_div" class="header">
    <a4j:outputPanel id="headerInfo">
        <h:form id="header_info">
            <h:panelGrid id="header_out1" columnClasses="left, right"  columns="2" width="98%" >    
                <h:panelGrid id="header_pnl1" columns="1" width="98%" >             
                    <h:graphicImage id="imglogo" value="../images/50.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle"/>      
                </h:panelGrid>

                <h:panelGrid id="user_info_pnl1" columns="1" >  
                    <h:panelGrid id="img_pnlGrid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <h:graphicImage id="notimg_img" value="../images/#{msgs.notimg}" 
                            rendered="#{!sbean.forUse}" />
                    </h:panelGrid>  
                    <h:panelGrid id="user_info_pnl2" columns="1" >  
                        <h:panelGroup id="about_userInfoPnlGroup">
                            <h:outputText id="is_daysLeft" styleClass="warning-msg" value="#{instadminbean.daysLeft}"/>
                            <rich:spacer width="100"/>
                            <h:outputText id="welcomeMessage_lbl" value="#{msgs.welcomeMessage}!" style="font-size=13px; solid black; font-family:tahoma; margin-right:4px; text-align:right;"/>
                            <rich:spacer width="10"/>
                            <h:outputText id="is_aboutuserName"  value="#{userAccount.userName}" styleClass="label-name" />
                            <rich:spacer width="100"/>
                            <a4j:commandLink id="linklogout" value="#{msgs.logout}" 
                            action="#{menubean.resetMenuActionVariables}" 
                            onclick="javascript:window.location = '../reports/logout.html'; return false;" 
                            rendered="true" style="margin-right:4px;color: #4F2170;"/>
                            <rich:spacer width="10"/>
                            <h:commandLink id="linkhelp" value="#{msgs.help}" rendered="true" onclick="window.open('pdf/#{msgs.homeguidename}#nameddest=About')" type="button" style="margin-right:4px;color: #4F2170;"/>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </h:panelGrid>      
                </h:panelGrid>          
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form> 
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</div>
```

Thanks,

Dorian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link contains this:

```
onclick="javascript:window.location = '../reports/logout.html'; return false;"
```

The `return false` will prevent the link from doing any postback to the server. You have to remove this code and it should work.

Comment: It works. But if I want to leave there "return false" ? There is any other way in doing this? Probably not.

Comment: You will have to trigger the navigation from the action method. This way you can execute your logout code and send the user to a different page after that.

Comment: How can i do that with this code? Should I leave "return false" in onclick and move the rest in action ?

Comment: Remove the onclick stuff completely and use standard JSF navigation: http://www.jsftutorials.net/jsf-navigation-by-examples.html

Comment: I remove onclick and replace it with concomplete:        action="#{menubean.resetMenuActionVariables}" 
oncomplete="javascript:window.location = '../reports/logout.html';return false;"